# cocos2d change sprite texture

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cctexturecache

I want to change a sprite texture with another texture from a sprite sheet

```
//normal sprite
character = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"char1.png"];

//change texture
[character setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"char2.png"]]];
```

but this gives me an error.I have tried without spriteWithSpriteFrameName and it gives me a 
blank texture.

```
//error
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCSprite lastPathComponent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xab32580'
```

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Shall try [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"char1.png"]; ?

Comment: it's works but I want to call the texture from a spritesheet

Comment: Is everything ok with sharedSpriteFrameCache? How do you add frames there? Also if it has problem with last path component try quickfix @"char1", maybe it has such name in the framechache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the displayFrame on the CCSprite, e.g.,

```
[character setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] 
                        spriteFrameByName:@"char2.png"];
```

Answer (score 2):

AddImage takes input imageName(NSString) not sprite(CCSprite).

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:TEX_IMAGE_NAME];
```

Here some useful code for you that solve your crash:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"char2.png"];
[crane setTexture:sprite.texture]; //Already allocated memory? if not thn try below
//crane = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:sprite.texture];
//crane = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:sprite.texture rect:rect];
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.as I mentioned in my question,above code gives move a black blank texture.why?

Comment: make sure sprite sheet is already loaded, position and z-order of sprite is correct -

Comment: check spriteWithSpriteFrameName return nil or right sprite object..debug !